# Copy-Paste crashes VBA

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste, paste

I have the following code:

```
Private Sub Update_To_Search_Click()
'add the user id and date in the lock and date columns
Dim r As Range
Dim wb As Workbook
 Set wb = Workbooks("GOOD")
 Set r = ActiveCell
 For i = 1 To Rows.count
     Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)
     If r.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
         r.Select
         GoTo Continue
     End If
 Next

Continue:
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 67).Select
If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
    ActiveCell.Value = UCase(Environ("UserName"))
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Copy
    wb.Activate
    Sheets("GoodDBData").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

Else
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Copy
    wb.Activate
    Sheets("GoodDBData").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End If
End sub
```

When run, it keeps spinning [not responding]. I have been using the Paste coding many times and it never happened before.

Any idea why?
Thank you

Comment: "Crashes" and "doesn't work" are poor problem descriptions that don't really help make a good, clear question. Feel free to [edit] your post to include the specific error you're getting, and what specific statement is causing it.

Answer (score 2):

[Avoid using `.Select`/`.Activate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).  Also, using `GoTo` is generally frowned upon.

Also, you most likely don't want to actually loop through every single row in Excel.  This can cause it to hang up/error out.

This code should work, I think I kept it as you were intending:

```
Private Sub Update_To_Search_Click()
'add the user id and date in the lock and date columns
Dim r       As Range
Dim wb      As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks("GOOD")
Set r = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")       ' CHANGE THIS WORKSHEET to the correct name, and update the starting cell!!!!!!!
For i = 1 To wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(rows.count,1).End(xlUp).Row ' Change this to the column with the most data
    Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)
    If r.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
        If r.Offset(0, 67).Value = "" Then
            r.Offset(0, 67).Value = UCase(Environ("UserName"))
            r.Offset(0, 67).Offset(0, 1).Value = Now
            r.Offset(0, 67).EntireRow.Copy wb.Sheets("GoodDBData").Range("A2").Paste
        Else
            r.EntireRow.Copy
            wb.Sheets("GoodDBData").Range("A2").Paste
        End If
    End If
Next
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: I was looping to find the unhidden row. I'm initially doing a filter based on some criteria and then I want to take the row that is filtered (hence the unhidden row) and copy-paste it in the wb workbook.

Comment: I get a Run Time error 92 For loop not initialized? I still very new to VBA, would you have any idea what this error is about?

Comment: @ValS - Hmm - what line throws the error? You may need to add `Dim i as Long` if you have `Option Explicit` on (which you should).  I tried on my comp and I can begin the loop.  Check that the worksheet names and workbook references are correct.

Comment: this is actually part of a userform button command. Should I add Option Explicit at the beginning of the Userform?